# Hash-optimization and Wilson-maze generation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, lua, maze

I've finished optimization of Wilson algorithm (maze generation) from "silly and slow" algorithm of choosing unvisited cells:

```
function aux.wilson()
local unvisited_cells = aux.width * aux.height 

local y, x = math.random(aux.sy, aux.height), math.random(aux.sx, aux.width)
aux.grid[y][x].visited = true
unvisited_cells = unvisited_cells - 1

local stx, sty
-- Here is a bad part   
while true do
    stx, sty = math.random(aux.sx, aux.width), math.random(aux.sy, aux.height) -- Start point
    if aux.grid[sty][stx].visited == false then break end
end

local ix, iy = stx, sty -- sub-vertecies

while unvisited_cells ~= 0 do
    if aux.grid[iy][ix].visited == true then 
        aux.grid[sty][stx].visited = true
        while unvisited_cells ~= 0 do
            if stx == ix and sty == iy then 
-- Here is a bad part
                while true do
                    stx, sty = math.random(aux.sx, aux.width), math.random(aux.sy, aux.height) 
                    if aux.grid[sty][stx].visited == false then break end
                end
                break
            else unvisited_cells = unvisited_cells - 1 end

            local dir = aux.grid[sty][stx].dir
            if dir == "UP" then
                aux.grid[sty-1][stx].visited = true
                aux.grid[sty-1][stx].bottom_wall = false
                sty = sty - 1
            elseif dir == "DOWN" then
                aux.grid[sty+1][stx].visited = true
                aux.grid[sty][stx].bottom_wall = false
                sty = sty + 1
            elseif dir == "LEFT" then
                aux.grid[sty][stx-1].visited = true
                aux.grid[sty][stx-1].right_wall = false
                stx = stx - 1
            elseif dir == "RIGHT" then
                aux.grid[sty][stx+1].visited = true
                aux.grid[sty][stx].right_wall = false
                stx = stx + 1
            end
        end
        ix, iy = stx, sty
    end

    local dir = aux.dirs[math.random(1, 4)]
    if dir == "UP" then -- UP
        if iy-1 >= aux.sy then
            aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "UP"
            iy = iy - 1
        end
    elseif dir == "DOWN" then -- DOWN 
        if iy+1 <= aux.height then 
            aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "DOWN"
            iy = iy + 1
        end
    elseif dir == "RIGHT" then -- RIGHT
        if ix+1 <= aux.width then
            aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "RIGHT"
            ix = ix + 1
        end
    elseif dir == "LEFT" then -- LEFT
        if ix-1 >= aux.sx then
            aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "LEFT"
            ix = ix - 1
        end
    end
end
end

// Don't mind about dirs-part, only unvisited-cells choosing matter.
```

to a little bit more clever:

```
function aux.wilson()
local unvisited_cells = aux.width * aux.height
local CellsHash = aux.hashCells(aux.grid)
local key = next(CellsHash, nil)
local vx, vy = aux.deHashKey(key)
CellsHash[key] = nil
aux.grid[vy][vx].visited = true

unvisited_cells = unvisited_cells - 1

key = next(CellsHash, nil)
vx, vy = aux.deHashKey(key)
CellsHash[key] = nil

local stx, sty = vx, vy

local ix, iy = stx, sty -- sub-vertecies

while unvisited_cells ~= 0 do
    if aux.grid[iy][ix].visited == true then 
        aux.grid[sty][stx].visited = true
        CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx, sty)] = nil
        while unvisited_cells ~= 0 do
            if stx == ix and sty == iy then 
                key = next(CellsHash, nil)
                vx, vy = aux.deHashKey(key)
                CellsHash[key] = nil

                stx, sty = vx, vy
                break
            else unvisited_cells = unvisited_cells - 1 end

            local dir = aux.grid[sty][stx].dir
            if dir == "UP" then
                aux.grid[sty-1][stx].visited = true
                    CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx, sty-1)] = nil
                aux.grid[sty-1][stx].bottom_wall = false
                sty = sty - 1
            elseif dir == "DOWN" then
                aux.grid[sty+1][stx].visited = true
                CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx, sty+1)] = nil
                aux.grid[sty][stx].bottom_wall = false
                sty = sty + 1
            elseif dir == "LEFT" then
                aux.grid[sty][stx-1].visited = true
                CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx-1, sty)] = nil
                aux.grid[sty][stx-1].right_wall = false
                stx = stx - 1
            elseif dir == "RIGHT" then
                aux.grid[sty][stx+1].visited = true
                CellsHash[aux.hashKey(stx+1, sty)] = nil
                aux.grid[sty][stx].right_wall = false
                stx = stx + 1
            end
        end
        ix, iy = stx, sty
    end

    local dir = aux.dirs[math.random(1, 4)]
    if dir == "UP" then -- UP
        if iy-1 >= aux.sy then
            aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "UP"
            iy = iy - 1
        end
    elseif dir == "DOWN" then -- DOWN 
        if iy+1 <= aux.height then 
            aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "DOWN"
            iy = iy + 1
        end
    elseif dir == "RIGHT" then -- RIGHT
        if ix+1 <= aux.width then
            aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "RIGHT"
            ix = ix + 1
        end
    elseif dir == "LEFT" then -- LEFT
        if ix-1 >= aux.sx then
            aux.grid[iy][ix].dir = "LEFT"
            ix = ix - 1
        end
    end
end
end
    function aux.hashKey(x, y)
return x * aux.height + (y - 1)
end

function aux.deHashKey(value)
return math.floor(value/aux.height), value%aux.height + 1
end

function aux.hashCells(grid)
    local vtable = {}
    for yk, yv in pairs(grid) do
        for xk, xv in pairs(yv) do
            if xv.visited == false then
                vtable[aux.hashKey(xk, yk)] = xv 
            end
        end
    end
    return vtable
end
```

And I noticed, that on the small grid (100x100), it works almost the same, but on the bigger grid (like 1000x1000), first version works in about 3-4 seconds, but the second version just freezes. And I really can' understand why. I don't see any operations, that can cause big-time issues.

I will really appreciate any advice or comments about optimization and speed of the both algorithm. 
Thank you!

UPD1: Ok, after some research and profiling I've found, that the problem was in a next function. Hash-table and collision solving-mechanism that are hidden behind Lua next-function are really slow for this purpose.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Created topic there too. But I am not sure, that it differs a lot.

Comment: @RussDragon - Thank you for the phrase you have coined ("original Lua intimidation").  It is quite suitable for some Lua language features :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Ahah, only now I noticed what I've written, sry xD